# Exclude columns in R calling column names

Tags: r

Suppose I have a matrix called `mymat`. I need to exclude columns `key` and `AMLM12014N-R` and make another matrix called `newmat`. I can simply do this like this: `newmat <- mymat[,-c(1,4)]`, but is there a way to do it by calling column name itself? Something like this: `newmat <- mymat[,-c("key","AMLM12014N-R")]` ?

```
mymat <- structure(c("chr5:12111", "chr5:12111", "chr5:12113", "chr5:12114", 
"chr5:12118", "0N", "0N", "1N", "0N", "0N", "00", "00", "00", 
"11", "10", "00", "00", "1N", "0N", "00"), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("34", "35", "36", "37", "38"), c("key", "AMLM12001KP", 
    "AMAS-11.3-Diagnostic", "AMLM12014N-R")))
```

Comment: Searching the exact title of your post in Google gives you a number of answers from Stackoverflow. If you can think of a title, you can search using that title before posting another question. You've asked 28 questions in December alone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setdiff`

```
mymat[,setdiff(colnames(mymat), c("key","AMLM12014N-R"))]
```

Or `%in%`

```
mymat[,!colnames(mymat) %in% c("key","AMLM12014N-R")]
```